# Learning to use Tweepy and Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently trying to learn the Twitter API within Python. My code is this:

```
import tweepy


consumer_key = "Consumer Key"
consumer_secret = "Consumer Secret"
access_token = "Access Token"
access_token_secret = "Access Token Secret"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_acess_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet = "This tweet was made from a program"
api.update_status(status=tweet)
```

However this is the error that the code is giving me:

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do I really need to apply for further access just to tweet one thing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a newer (v2) API. You should use [tweepy.Client](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html) to be able to use the new endpoints without signing up.